# Query with sub-query performs terrible

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, query-optimization

I'm having a problem with the performance of the following query, I want to get some info about saleslines and per salesline I want to find out the last date is was received in stock:

```
SELECT        XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTABLE.SALESNUMBER, XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTABLE.DEBTORACCOUNT, XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTABLE.DELIVERYNAME, 
                     XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTABLE.DELIVERYADDRESS3, XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTABLE.REQUISNUMBER, XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTABLE.CUSTOMERREF, 
                     XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTABLE.ROUTE, XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTABLE.ROUTENUMBER, XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTABLE.CMPVWSTATUS, 
                     XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTABLE.CMPLOGISTIEK, XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTABLE.USVEHICLE, XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTABLE.ELCSALSTCALL, 
                     XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTABLE.ELCSALSTOK, XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTABLE.ELCEDICODE, XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTRANS.ITEMNUMBER, 
                     XAL_SUPERVISOR.STOCKTABLE.ITEMNAME, XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTRANS.QTYORDERED, XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTRANS.STOCKLOC AS REGELLOC, 
                     XAL_SUPERVISOR.STOCKTABLE.STOCKLOC AS STDLOC, XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTABLE.DELIVERYDATE, XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTABLE.DATASET, 
                     XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTABLE.CMPCORRECTIE, XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTRANS.ELCORGQTYORDERED AS ORG_BESTELD, 
                     XAL_SUPERVISOR.STOCKTABLE.CMPVERVALLEN,
                         (SELECT        (SUM(STS.ENTEREDQTY) + SUM(STS.RECEIVED) - SUM(STS.DRAWN))
                           FROM            XAL_SUPERVISOR.STOCKSUM STS
                           WHERE        STS.ITEMNUMBER = XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTRANS.ITEMNUMBER AND STS.DATASET = 'CMP'
                           GROUP BY STS.ITEMNUMBER) AS VOORRAAD,
                         (SELECT        SUM(STS.ORDERED)
                           FROM            XAL_SUPERVISOR.STOCKSUM STS
                           WHERE        STS.ITEMNUMBER = XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTRANS.ITEMNUMBER AND STS.DATASET = 'CMP'
                           GROUP BY STS.ITEMNUMBER) AS BESTELD,
                         (SELECT        SUM(STS.RESERVPHYSICAL)
                           FROM            XAL_SUPERVISOR.STOCKSUM STS
                           WHERE        STS.ITEMNUMBER = XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTRANS.ITEMNUMBER AND STS.DATASET = 'CMP'
                           GROUP BY STS.ITEMNUMBER) AS GERESERVEERD,
                         (SELECT        DDT.QTY
                           FROM            XAL_SUPERVISOR.DEBDLVTRANS DDT
                           WHERE        DDT.TRANSID = XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTRANS.TRANSID AND DDT.DATASET = 'CMP') AS PAKBONAANTAL,
                         (SELECT        DIT.QTY
                           FROM            XAL_SUPERVISOR.DEBINVTRANS DIT
                           WHERE        DIT.TRANSID = XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTRANS.TRANSID AND DIT.DATASET = 'CMP') AS FACTUURAANTAL,
                         (SELECT        MAX(ST.DATEPHYSICAL)
                           FROM            XAL_SUPERVISOR.STOCKTRANS ST
                           WHERE        ST.ITEMNUMBER = XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTRANS.ITEMNUMBER AND ST.DATASET = 'CMP' AND ST.StatusInFlow < 3 AND ST.DCType = 2) 
                     AS LTSTGELEVERD
FROM            XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTABLE, XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTRANS, XAL_SUPERVISOR.STOCKTABLE
WHERE        XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTABLE.DATASET = XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTRANS.DATASET AND 
                     XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTABLE.SALESNUMBER = XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTRANS.SALESNUMBER AND 
                     XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTRANS.ITEMNUMBER = XAL_SUPERVISOR.STOCKTABLE.ITEMNUMBER AND 
                     XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTRANS.DATASET = XAL_SUPERVISOR.STOCKTABLE.DATASET AND (XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTABLE.DELIVERYDATE = :Leverdatum) AND 
                     (XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTABLE.DATASET = 'CMP') AND (XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTABLE.CMPCORRECTIE = 0)
```

This part slows it down (without it it runs in < 10 seconds):

```
   (SELECT        MAX(ST.DATEPHYSICAL)
                           FROM            XAL_SUPERVISOR.STOCKTRANS ST
                           WHERE        ST.ITEMNUMBER = XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTRANS.ITEMNUMBER AND ST.DATASET = 'CMP' AND ST.StatusInFlow < 3 AND ST.DCType = 2) 
                     AS LTSTGELEVERD
```

When I run it in SQL plus I see it fetches the main query and then pauses for a long time to fetch the above subquery?

Comment: check if your table `STOCKTRANS` is correctly indexed

Comment: There are consultants who make very fine livings from tuning other people's shonky code.  They couldn't charge so much if it was simp;ly a matter of looking at a query and saying, 'Change that line there'.  There are a huge number of factors which might cause bad performance.  Data volumes, data skew, bad disks, insufficient memory, stale statistics, missing indexes, wrong indexes, disk sorting.  Badly written SQL is just one of mnay things it could be.

Comment: As @Majid said: check that there are the right indexes and that the query plan actually uses them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things you can try:

- The fourth and fifth subqueries just get a scalar value, so they can be put into the main body of the query. It looks like you're using subqueries here to avoid a `LEFT JOIN`.
- The first, second, third and sixth subqueries can be combined using a Common Table Expression (CTE), otherwise known as the Oracle `WITH` clause. As with the other subquery values, these will now have to be incorporated using a `LEFT JOIN`.

Also, this comes out a lot easier if you use ANSI join syntax. Here's the answer (though note I've left out a lot of the "bystander" columns so it will be somewhat compact; you can add those back in if this solution works for you):

```
WITH StkSum AS (
  SELECT
    STS.ITEMNUMBER,
    SUM(STS.ENTEREDQTY) + SUM(STS.RECEIVED) - SUM(STS.DRAWN) AS VOORRAAD,
    SUM(STS.ORDERED) AS BESTELD,
    SUM(STS.RESERVPHYSICAL) AS GERESERVEERD,
    MAX(ST.DATEPHYSICAL) AS LTSTGELEVERD
  FROM XAL_SUPERVISOR.STOCKSUM STS
  INNER JOIN XAL_SUPERVISOR.STOCKTRANS ST ON STS.ITEMNUMBER = ST.ITEMNUMBER
  WHERE STS.DATASET = 'CMP'
    AND ST.DATASET = 'CMP'
    AND ST.StatusInFlow < 3
    AND ST.DCType = 2
)
SELECT
  XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTABLE.SALESNUMBER,
  ... all those SALESTABLE and SALESTRANS and STOCKTABLE columns ...,
  StkSum.VOORRAAD,
  StkSum.BESTELD,
  StkSum.GERESERVEERD,
  NVL(XAL_SUPERVISOR.DEBDLVTRANS.QTY, 0) AS PAKBONAANTAL,
  NVL(XAL_SUPERVISOR.DEBINVTRANS.QTY, 0) AS FACTUURAANTAL,
  StkSum.LTSTGELEVERD
FROM XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTABLE
INNER JOIN XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTRANS ON
  SalesTable.DataSet = SalesTrans.DataSet AND
  SalesTable.SalesNumber = SalesTrans.SalesNumber
INNER JOIN XAL_SUPERVISOR.STOCKTABLE ON
  SalesTrans.ItemNumber = StockTable.ItemNumber AND
  SalesTrans.DataSet = StockTable.DataSet
LEFT OUTER JOIN StkSum ON StkSum.ITEMNUMBER = SalesTrans.ITEMNUMBER
LEFT OUTER JOIN XAL_SUPERVISOR.DEBDLVTRANS DDT ON DDT.TRANSID = SalesTrans.TRANSID
LEFT OUTER JOIN XAL_SUPERVISOR.DEBINVTRANS DIT ON DIT.TRANSID = SalesTrans.TRANSID
WHERE
  (XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTABLE.DELIVERYDATE = :Leverdatum) AND 
  (XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTABLE.DATASET = 'CMP') AND
  (XAL_SUPERVISOR.SALESTABLE.CMPCORRECTIE = 0) AND
  DDT.DATASET = 'CMP' AND
  DIT.DATASET = 'CMP'
```

Finally, note that *due to the sheer number of tables and columns and conditions, I'd be shocked if the query above was 100% right*. I tried my best, but my best may not be good enough here :) Tweakage will likely be needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running this query from an application like .net or coldfusion, you could run the queries separately and join them in the application.  With .net it would be linq to DataTable and coldfusion it would be query of queries.

You can do the same sort of thing in a stored procedure.  Populate a temp table with the data from the subquery and join to the temp table instead.

While these sorts of things are counter-intuitive, and might even represent worst practices, sometimes they are appropriate for the situation at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Subqueries in SELECT clauses tend to be poor performers One way to improve this is to use an inline view or WITH clause to caluclate the max per ITEMNUMBER  and then join to it.

```
WITH datephysical_max as
    (SELECT Max(ST.datephysical) max_ , ST.itemnumber 
        FROM   xal_supervisor.stocktrans ST 
        WHERE  
               AND ST.dataset = 'CMP' 
               AND ST.statusinflow < 3 
               AND ST.dctype = 2
        GROUP BY )  
SELECT 
      ....,
      st.LTSTGELEVERD
FROM   xal_supervisor.salestable 
       inner join xal_supervisor.salestrans 
               ON xal_supervisor.salestable.dataset = 
                  xal_supervisor.salestrans.dataset 
                  AND xal_supervisor.salestable.salesnumber = 
                      xal_supervisor.salestrans.salesnumber 
                  AND xal_supervisor.salestrans.itemnumber = 
                      xal_supervisor.stocktable.itemnumber 
       inner join xal_supervisor.stocktable 
               ON xal_supervisor.salestrans.dataset = 
                  xal_supervisor.stocktable.dataset 
       INNER JOIN datephysical_max st
               ON ST.itemnumber = xal_supervisor.salestrans.itemnumber 
WHERE  ( xal_supervisor.salestable.deliverydate = :Leverdatum ) 
       AND ( xal_supervisor.salestable.dataset = 'CMP' ) 
       AND ( xal_supervisor.salestable.cmpcorrectie = 0 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your select that slows down the query has the following thing making it slow:

1. math (the less than ) can case indexes not to be used.  consider
   changing to an in list if list is small
2. if you don't have indexes as follows it will be slow

   one on (ST.item_number, ST.dataset, ST.status_in_flow, ST.dctype)
   one on XAL_SUPERVISOR(itemNumber)
   one on datephysical can be used by max since it causes order by.
3. consider first running with query for all the where clause then do max based on it.

If the indexes aren't used there are many reasons.  Math in where clause, If large rowcount then definantly consider item 1 so index will be used.  Also, if column can be null, to_upper etc you can use function based indexes.